# Int variable subtraction affecting for loop index

Tags: c, for-loop

I am using a for loop to walk through the elements of char array `teste`. Within this loop, I am using an int variable called `stack_index`, for some controls. The program below runs fine, see that, its result is the value of `stack_index` repeated 18 times (size of char array `teste`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t char_size (char* c) {
   return strlen(c);
}

int main() {
    char teste[] = "Este *teste* string";
    size_t n = char_size(teste);
    char stack[20];
    int stack_index = 0;
    for(int i; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d", stack_index);
    }
}
```

**Result of program above:**

```
0000000000000000000
```

But, when I add just the line `stack_index--` inside the loop, the loop index breaks in some crazy way. See that the result of this program is the values -1, -2 and -3. This result is indicating that the for loop is running only 3 times (instead of 18). But why this is happening? Why subtracting (or adding) 1 from the `stack_index` variable at each iteration, is affecting the loop index variable `i`? This makes no sense to me, since the `i` variable is the index variable of the loop, not `stack_index`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t char_size (char* c) {
   return strlen(c);
}

int main() {
    char teste[] = "Este *teste* string";
    size_t n = char_size(teste);
    char stack[20];
    int stack_index = 0;
    for(int i; i < n; i++){
        stack_index--;
        printf("%d", stack_index);
    }
}
```

**Result of program above:**

```
-1-2-3
```

Comment: `int i;` You never initialize `i`. It will have an *indeterminate* value (think of it as garbage).

Answer (score 0):

@Some programmer dude comment answer the problem. I did not initialize the `i` variable with some initial value (like `0`). This mistake was breaking the loop, not the `stack_index--` line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t char_size (char* c) {
   return strlen(c);
}

int main() {
    char teste[] = "Este *teste* string";
    size_t n = char_size(teste);
    char stack[20];
    int stack_index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        stack_index--;
        printf("%d", stack_index);
    }
}
```

**Result of program above:**

```
-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19
```